# base cleaned after rebuild project

Tags: c#

I have c# project and locale database inside. I run application everything ok. I can add new rows to database and data is saved. but when I do a changes or rebuild project and run it again database is cleaned. can someone tell me why this happend please ?

Comment: Can you post your code for retrieving/setting data to the database? That sounds really weird. Cleaning the project shouldn't have anything to do with dropping rows in a table. Unless you are using some kind of post-script.

Comment: Database is a broad term.  It sounds like that the data is being stored in memory and when the processes ends the data goes away.

Comment: I use the Entity Data Model for work with database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My educated guess:
Probably you have build action "copy" on your database file. so it gets copied every time you build. the full one is in /bin, the empty one in your project, you overwrite it every time, end of story:)

Comment: Yes, you are right. db is copied. but is it normal? :)

Comment: well, you can either deploy a full version of the db with the installer or make sql scripts to write your db during install. usually you dont have the database in /bin because it gets installed to programs folder, where you dont have rights to write or edit files (during normal execution of your program), so yes, this is normal

Comment: Thank you! I hope db will not cleaned when application will finished